# Selecting rows where values in one column are different, other column(s) values are similar and values of Date columns are correct

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following columns:
ID,Code,DST,Short_text,Long_text,Date_from,Date_until

Here is the dataset:

```
ID  Code    DST   Short_text      Long_text     Date_From    Date_Until

1   B 01    B 1     Bez1           Bezirk1       29.10.1999   13.01.2020
1   B 01    B 1     Bez1           Bezirk1       14.01.2020   31.12.9999 
2   B 02    B 2     Bez2           Bezirk2       29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
3   B 03    B 3     Bez3           Bezirk3       14.01.2020   31.12.9999 
4   B 04    B 4     Bez4           Bezirk4       29.10.1999   13.01.2020  
4   B 04    B 4     Bez4           Bezirk4       14.01.2020   31.12.9999 
97  M 51    M 52    MA 51          Sport         29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
96  M 51    M 51    MA 51          Sport         14.01.2020   31.12.9999 
98  M 55    M 53    MA 53          Dance         29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
99  M 55    M 54    MA 54          Skating       14.01.2020   31.12.9999 
100 M 56    M 59    MA 57          Football      29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
101 M 56    M 56    MA 56          Tennis        29.10.1999   31.12.9999
```

I want to select rows, such that they have different ID AND (they have similar Code OR SImilar Short_text OR simmlar long_text) AND Correct Date_from - Date_Until.

**Definition of correct Date_from - Date_Until:**

```
1.Date_ from < Date_Until
2.Both fields are not Null
3. WHEN PREV_DATE_UNTIL = DATE_FROM - 1 OR PREV_DATE_UNTIL is null THEN 'OK'(PREV_DATE_UNTIL using lag operator)
4. WHEN NEXT_DATE_FROM = DATE_UNTIL + 1 OR NEXT_DATE_FROM is null THEN 'OK'(NEXT_DATE_FROM using lead operator)
```

**Not correct:**

```
WHEN WHEN NEXT_DATE_FROM > DATE_UNTIL + 1 THEN 'Gaps in Dates'
WHEN WHEN NEXT_DATE_FROM < DATE_UNTIL + 1 THEN 'Overlapping dates'
```

Basically what I mean, that historization of the data must be correct(no overlapping)

At the end I want to select the following rows:

```
97  M 51    M 52    MA 51          Sport         29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
96  M 51    M 51    MA 51          Sport         14.01.2020   31.12.9999
```

Because they have different ID and similar Code or short_text or long_text and dates are correct according to the definition

And

```
98  M 55    M 53    MA 53          Dance         29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
99  M 55    M 54    MA 54          Skating       14.01.2020   31.12.9999
```

Because they have different ID and similar Code and dates are correct according to the definition

Rows:

```
100 M 56    M 59    MA 57          Football      29.10.1999   13.01.2020 
101 M 56    M 56    MA 56          Tennis        29.10.1999   31.12.9999
```

Should NOT be selected, because they have different ID and similar Code BUT they have incorrect Dates(they are overlapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be something like that:

```
with t as (
  select row_number() over (order by date_from, date_until) rn, 
         id, code, dst, short_text, long_text, date_from, 
         nullif(date_until, date '9999-12-31') date_until 
    from data)
select rna, rnb, description, t.* 
  from t 
  join (
    select a.rn rna, b.rn rnb,
           case when b.date_from = a.date_until + 1 then 'OK'
                when b.date_from > a.date_until + 1 then 'gaps'
                when b.date_from < a.date_until + 1 then 'overlapping'
           end description
      from t a 
      join t b on a.id <> b.id and a.rn < b.rn
              and (a.code = b.code or a.short_text = b.short_text 
                                   or a.long_text = b.long_text)) pairs
        on rn in (rna, rnb)
```

result is:

```
   RNA    RNB DESCRIPTION    RN         ID CODE DST  SHORT_TEXT LONG_TEXT DATE_FROM   DATE_UNTIL
------ ------ ----------- ----- ---------- ---- ---- ---------- --------- ----------- -----------
     1      7 overlapping     1        100 M 56 M 59 MA 57      Football  1999-10-29  2020-01-13
     1      7 overlapping     7        101 M 56 M 56 MA 56      Tennis    1999-10-29  
     3      8 OK              3         98 M 55 M 53 MA 53      Dance     1999-10-29  2020-01-13
     3      8 OK              8         99 M 55 M 54 MA 54      Skating   2020-01-14  
     6      9 OK              6         97 M 51 M 52 MA 51      Sport     1999-10-29  2020-01-13
     6      9 OK              9         96 M 51 M 51 MA 51      Sport     2020-01-14
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2f51871a7acf9b5e7528320c00bbd1a6)</sup>**

I numbered rows, self joined such data and dressed your logic in `case when` syntax. I tested on your examples, in case of any mistakes please provide [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) if possible.